# Extract Information/cleaning data from CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, nlp

I have a dataset provided properties.csv (4000 rows and 6 columns). The csv file including many features some of these features are numerical and some of them are nominal (features contain text). Suppose the features in this dataset are

```
id
F1 
F2
F3
F4 
Price
```

Examples of the content of each feature:

id (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) ---> 44525
                                 44859
                                 45465

F1 (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) ---> "Stunning 6 bedroom villa in the heart of the 
                                  Golden Mile, Marbella" 
                                 "Villa for sale in Rocio de NagÃ¼eles, Marbella 
                                  Golden Mile"
                                 "One level 5 bedroom villa for sale in 
                                  NagÃ¼eles"

F2 (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) --->  "Fireplace, Elevator, Terrace, Mountain view, 
                                   Freight Elevator, Air conditioning, Patio, 
                                   Guest toilet, Garden, Balcony, Sea/lake view, 
                                   Built-in kitchen"
                                   "Mountain view"
                                   "Elevator, Terrace, Alarm system, Mountain 
                                    view, Swimming pool, Air conditioning, 
                                    Basement, Sea/lake view"

F3 (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) - contains numerical values --->  0
                                                              0
                                                              0

F4 (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) - contains numerical values ---> 393
                                                             640
                                                             4903
F3 (row 1 to 3 in CSV File) - contains numerical values ---> 4400000
                                                             2400000
                                                             1900000

In F1, I am looking to do the following:

1- Extract the type of the properties (apartment’, ‘house’ or ‘Villa’) and put it in a separate feature (independent variable) calls "Type" in CSV file. After that, I want to separate them in groups (apartments group, houses group, Vilas group) with calculating the mean price of each type group.
2- Extract the location of each property (locations can be: Alenquer, Quinta da Marinha, Golden Mile, Nagüeles) and put it in a separate feature (independent variable) calls "Location" in csv file.

I am a beginner in NLP. I tried to write this code to extract information "Apartment" from F1, but it does not work probably:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

properties = pd.read_csv (r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/properties.csv')
Extract "Apartment" from F1
Title= DataFrame(properties,columns= ['F1'])

for line in F1: 
        #return list of apartments in that line
        x = re.findall("\apartment", line) 
        #if a date is found
         if len(x) != 0:
         print(x)
```

I need your help to fix this code and what should I do to extract the other information ‘houses’ and ‘Villa’ from F1.

After that, Create a property dataset in this format and save it as a csv file:

```
id
Location (Information extracted from F1)
type (information extracted from F1 in groups "apartments’, ‘houses’, ‘Villas’")
F1
F2
F3
F4
Price
```

In case, F1 does not contain the type of some properties "Blank field (no text)", what should I do to deal with the blanks fields (no text) in F1 and extract the type of the properties from other properties?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by writing the following code, but I still have the same problem:

Comment: import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
properties = pd.read_csv (r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/properties.csv')   

F1= DataFrame(properties,columns= ['F1'])

data = []
for row in F1:
    title_pattern = 'apartment'
    comp = re.compile(title_pattern)
    href = re.findall(comp, str(row))
    for x in href:
        data.append(x)

Comment: I need really to your help

Comment: It would help if you could copy/paste a few actual rows from your CSV into your question (and the header) and show what output you are trying to get for those.

Comment: Hi Martin, I worked on your comment. Look forward to helping me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('appt_info.csv', delimiter=';')

def extract_housing_type(text):
    # Do a regular expression search for the pattern
    match = re.search('(apartment|house|villa)s?', text, flags=re.I)
    if match is not None:
        return match.group(0)  # return the value of the match
    return 'Unknown'  # return a default value if there is no match


df['Type'] = df.F1.apply(lambda x: extract_housing_type(x))  # assign the output to a new column
```

This should give you a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      id                                                 F1  \
0  44525  Stunning 6 bedroom villa in the heart of the G...   
1  44859  Villa for sale in Rocio de Nageles, Marbella G...   
2  45465      One level 5 bedroom villa for sale in Nageles   

                                                  F2  F3    F4    Price   Type  
0  Fireplace, Elevator, Terrace, Mountain view, F...   0   393  4400000  villa  
1                                      Mountain view   0   640  2400000  Villa  
2  Elevator, Terrace, Alarm system, Mountain view...   0  4903  1900000  villa
```